# can't get attribute from session

Tags: session, servlets

I have a web application, and I want to use an object, which I save in the seesion.
When I run the web app in eclipse it's work fine, but it dosen't work on the browser.
The object which I get from the session is null.

In the servlet I have this code:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("wrapper", wrapper);
```

and in the jsp, where I need this attribute I have the code:

```
WrapperMLP wrapper = ((WrapperMLP) request.getSession().getAttribute("wrapper"));
```

thanks in advance

Comment: In JSP scriptlets, session can be accesed simply with `session.getXXXX`. You don't need to get it from the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a new session object in servlet as:-

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("wrapper",wrapper);
```

and in jsp write your code:

```
WrapperMLP wrapper = ((WrapperMLP) request.getSession().getAttribute("wrapper"));
```

Comment: I found the problem, in the browser, I insert the url to the jsp file. But I need to start from the servlet, which insert the wrapper to the seesion, and after that to move to the jsp file.